# Add reject/resolve to catch/success

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I use the following code and I wonder for best practise usage if I should add reject to 
this promise inside the catch?

```
run: function (req, res) {

        if (req) {
            return this._un(req).then(function() {  
                return proce.restart().then(function() {                    
                    return res.status(200).end("sucess");   
                    //Here should I use reslove
                });                                                             
            }).catch(function(err) {                
                return res.status(500).send("error: " + err);
                //Here should I use reject???               
            });                     
        }
        else {          
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {  
                reject("No application content found");
            });         
        }       
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't "add reject" to a promise. A promise is either unsettled, or settled (resolved/rejected).

If `req` is provided, your code currently returns a promise that will be resolved with the return value of `end` (if the restart was successful) or the return value of `send` (if it wasn't), which I believe in both cases is the response object itself (`res`).

If you want the caller to be aware of whether the restart was successful, then yes, you want to reject the promise instead; with ES2015 promises you can do that by throwing in `catch` and I assume Bluebird is similar:

```
.catch(function(err) {
    res.status(500).send("error: " + err);
    throw err; // Or `throw new Error(err);`, it depends on what `err` is and your convention
})
```

...or by using Bluebird's [`Promise.reject`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.reject.html) (which is also ES2015-compatible):

```
.catch(function(err) {
    res.status(500).send("error: " + err);
    return Promise.reject(err);
})
```

If you *don't* want the caller to be aware of whether the restart was successful, then don't.